# C initializing array C2059

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

What is wrong with this code:

```
Vertex *transformIntoVertex(float *v, int size){
    int i;
    float x_axis = x_0 + (x_Max/size);
    Vertex *axisVertices2[9];

    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        axisVertices2[i] = {{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }};
    }       
    return axisVertices2;    }

typedef struct
{
    float XYZW[4];
    float RGBA[4];
} Vertex;
```

I am getting this error:

```
 error C2059: syntax error : '{'
```

The error is on this line:

```
axisVertices2[i] = {{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }};
```

Can you suggest me a macro to fill in with my custom values, i must use constants cannot use variables

Comment: You're returning the address of a local variable (`&axisVertices2[0]`, what `axisVertices2` is converted to). That's the first wrong thing that jumps out.

Comment: yes i know. that is not the problem. the problem is on the line of the axisvertices2[i]. i'll fix that later

Comment: Also, `axisVertices2[i] = {{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }};` tries to set a `Vertex*` to a `Vertex`-initialiser.

Comment: @JohnHarrod One does not simply initialize,declare and assign values while looping  , all in one statement.It just cannot be done in C...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line is wrong

```
axisVertices2[i] = {{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }, { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }};
```

assignment with `{}` could be done only in the declaration phase of a variable

Comment: i must fill in the Vertex like this then: axisVertices2[i]->XYZW[0] = 0.0f; ?

Comment: ok. i'm sorry for the dumb question. I'm new to C, only know Java. I get to do this kind of mistakes. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do something like this. Note that I'm using `malloc` to create the space for the array. This will allow us to return the value from this function. I've also used a valid method to assign to `axisVertices2`.

If you use this though, whomever call `transformIntoVertex` is responsible for calling `free` on the pointer this function returns.

```
Vertex *transformIntoVertex(float *v, int size){
    int i;
    float x_axis = x_0 + (x_Max/size);
    Vertex *axisVertices2 = malloc(sizeof(Vertex) * size);

    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        axisVertices2[i].XYZW[0] = 0.0;
        axisVertices2[i].XYZW[1] = 0.0;
        axisVertices2[i].XYZW[2] = 0.0;
        axisVertices2[i].XYZW[3] = 1.0;

        axisVertices2[i].RGBA[0] = 1.0;
        axisVertices2[i].RGBA[1] = 1.0;
        axisVertices2[i].RGBA[2] = 1.0;
        axisVertices2[i].RGBA[3] = 1.0;
    }

    return axisVertices2;
}
```

Technically, you could also do something like this, but I doubt you'd see much of a performance boost. And I'd argue that the first version is more obvious, at least at this point.

```
Vertex *transformIntoVertex(float *v, int size){
    int i;
    float x_axis = x_0 + (x_Max/size);
    Vertex *axisVertices2 = malloc(sizeof(Vertex) * 9);

    static const Vertex default_value = {{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0}, {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0}};

    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        memcpy(&axisVertices2[i], &default_value, sizeof(Vertex));
    }

    return axisVertices2;
}
```